# Woocommerce REST API not working inside the plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to make woocommerce  plugin. 
I need to use woocommerce REST API. 
I tried REST API in localhost with single php file it works. But when I try to add that codes to the plugin. it doesn't work.

it gives me that warning message in admin area.

> The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your
>   site admin email inbox for instructions.

error log.

> [19-May-2019 07:07:14 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to
>   undefined method WooCommerce::get() in
>   D:\wamp64_SSD\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\myetsy\index.php:87
>   Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 D:\wamp64_SSD\www\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(286): etsy_func('')
>
> ## 1 D:\wamp64_SSD\www\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
>
> ## 2 D:\wamp64_SSD\www\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php(465): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
>
> ## 3 D:\wamp64_SSD\www\wordpress\wp-admin\admin.php(253): do_action('woocommerce_pag...')
>
> ## 4 {main}   thrown in D:\wamp64_SSD\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\myetsy\index.php on
>
> line 87

```html
<?php


require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;





$woocommerce = new Client(
    'http://localhost/wordpress',
    'ck_cb93e80be8b5866514b5e95f71055e3a8f2358d2',
    'cs_a0ec55a88a28475373a8ece2e303c40634f56511',
    [
  'wp_api'  => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v3' ,
  'verify_ssl' => false

    ]
);



function register_my_custom_submenu_page() {
    add_submenu_page( 'woocommerce', 'Etsy', 'Etsy', 'manage_options', 'etsy-link', 'etsy_func' ); 
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_submenu_page',99);

function etsy_func() {

echo '<h3>Title</h3>';
 
$data = [
    'name' => 'Premium Qualityssssssssssssss',
    'type' => 'simple',
    'regular_price' => '22.99',
    'description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.',
    'short_description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.',
    'categories' => [
        [
            'id' => 10
        ],
        [
            'id' => 14
        ]
    ],
    'images' => [
        [
            'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg'
        ],
        [
            'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_back.jpg'
        ]
    ]
];
global $woocommerce;
print_r($woocommerce->post('products', $data));



 
}
 
?>
```

Thanks in advance.